# How would you deseasonalize this data

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I am dealing with electricity prices, and they have 3 know "seasons":

- Prices during the day follow a pattern;
- Prices in the weekend are lower than during the week;
- In summer prices are different than in winter.

The three effects interact as well, i.e. in summer the daily pattern is different than during the winter. At the end of the question the "seasons" are summarised, with the daily effects displayed for each month, full lines are weekdays, dashed lines are weekends.

Now what is the best way to deseasonalize this data? I can think of a couple of options:

- Calculate with dummies the known effects, and subtract this from the original data. (This is what I have done, summary graph also attached at the bottom. In blue is the seasonal effect.);
- Work with differences, for example take the 24 hour difference to get rid of the daily effects. But can you do this to take out for example first the weekly effect and afterwards still the daily effect?
- Work with a moving average component that goes back 24 hours of even 7 days.

What option do you suggest?

Thanks in advance, and for those interested in the subject, this is a video explaining a very particular seasonal effect of electricity use http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCAzalhldg8.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72294/how-to-remove-seasonality-from-daily-electricity-demand for a similar question.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks. I have seen the question before, maybe I should rephrase my question as "do you think the method with dummy variables is a good one compared to the typical first differencing and are there any other methods?"

Comment: There are several entire books on seasonality directed at economists and econometricians (I am neither), so I suspect this question will seem (a) too broad (b) lacking in research effort to those in the field. Are there any other methods? is a way to cut your readership in this forum, as users with high reputation much prefer specific questions to invitations to write a review. I'll give you "unobserved components models" as one positive.